# The plot3d figure in matplotlib is somewhat canted

Tags: python, matplotlib, waterfall

I am using matplotlib to get a water fall figure, but the results look very strange. Anyone have any idea what could be wrong with it?
Here I attached the figures. The second one is the same data but in an ordinary plot. In the waterfall figure, why the color is not fully filled?

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
def water_fall_1(x,y,Z):
    #x=[...]
    #y=[...]
    #Z=[[z1],[z2],...z[ny]]
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
    from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    figs=[]
    for jc in range(len(y)):
        figs.append(list(zip(x,Z[jc])))
    x=np.array(x)
    y=np.array(y)
    Z=np.array(Z)
    xmin=np.floor(np.min((x.astype(np.float))))
    xmax=np.ceil(np.max((x.astype(np.float))))
    ymin=np.min((y.astype(np.float)))
    ymax=np.max((y.astype(np.float)))
    zmin=(np.min((Z.astype(np.float))))
    zmax=np.max((Z.astype(np.float)))

    fig=plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    poly = PolyCollection(figs, facecolors=colorConverter.to_rgba("r", alpha=0.5))
    ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=y.astype(np.float), zdir='y')
    ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
    ax.set_zlim(zmin,zmax)
    ax.set_xlabel('$\omega$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$T$')
    #ax.set_zlabel('$\\frac{1}{2}$')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You can add an exclamation mark in front of the image markdown to make them appear inline. Like this: `![Fig1][1]`

Comment: What do you mean by "not fully filled"?

Comment: Could you see that in the first figure, it looks like that some part of it have been cut?  The missing part is a triangle. What I expect is the red color(at x=0) will continues to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve ***is*** fully filled. I.e. the surface in between the points of the curve is red.

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

bottom=-0.3
x = np.linspace(0,6, num=50)
z = np.sinc(x-4)
verts = zip(x,z)

#verts=verts + [(x.max(),bottom),(x.min(),bottom)]

fig=plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
poly = PolyCollection([verts], facecolors="r", alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=1, zdir='y')
ax.set_xlim(x.min(),x.max())
ax.set_ylim(0,2)
ax.set_zlim(bottom,z.max())

plt.show()
```

which produces the following plot, where everything between the points of the curve is filled as expected.

[image]

If we now want to have the area between the curve and some bottom line filled, we would need to add some points,

```
verts=verts + [(x.max(),bottom),(x.min(),bottom)]
```

such that the bottom line is part of the curve and can thus be filled as well.
[image]